# testing functions that return a Maybe Monad

Tags: haskell, testing, monads, assertions, hspec

Say I have a function:

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead xs = Just $ head xs
```

And a test:

```
describe "Example.safeHead" $ do
  it "returns the head" $ do
    safeHead [1,2,3] `shouldBe` Just 1

  it "returns Nothing for an empty list" $
    safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing
```

This however produces:

```
No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘shouldBe’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Either a b)
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
  instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Eq (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
  instance (GHC.Arr.Ix i, Eq e) => Eq (GHC.Arr.Array i e)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Arr’
  ...plus 88 others
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  it "returns Nothing for an empty list"
  $ safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘do { it "returns the head"
        $ do { safeHead [...] `shouldBe` Just 1 };
        it "returns Nothing for an empty list"
        $ safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing }’
```

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: The type of `safeHead [] \`shouldBe\` Nothing` is ambiguous because there is nothing to tell the compiler which element type to use in comparisons of the list elements (of course, it does't matter, since there are no elements, but the compiler doesn't know that). You can fix it by giving an explicit type: `safeHead [] \`shouldBe\` (Nothing :: Maybe Int)`.

Answer (score 4):

As user2407038 commented, compiler doesn't know how to instantiate `a`. The fix he proposed is probably the best one -- you should specify type of `a` explicitly.

But for completeness I'd like to note, that there is other solution, [extended default rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

describe "Example.safeHead" $ do
  it "returns the head" $ do
    safeHead [1,2,3] `shouldBe` Just 1

  it "returns Nothing for an empty list" $
    safeHead [] `shouldBe` Nothing
```

The extension modifies [the standard defaulting rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) to include more cases, e.g. `Eq` type class.

**Added:** After some thinking I reconsider my answer a bit. Results of unit testing of polymorphic functions should not depend of a particular way to instantiate type variables. So probably extended default rules is The Right Thing in tests? I never used them it real code, so I can't say for sure, but it definitely worth thinking about.

Comment: very interesting. I'd love to know what the relative pros and cons of this solution are with respect to giving a type specification? Or is it literally "pros: less typing, cons: looser types"?

Comment: @AbrahamP basically yes, less typing is probably the only pros :)

Answer (score 2):

```
shouldBe                :: (Eq a, Show a) => a -> a -> Expectation
safeHead                ::         [a] ->    Maybe a
[]                      ::         [a]
safeHead []             ::                   Maybe a
Nothing                 ::                   Maybe a
shouldBe (safeHead [])  :: (Eq a, Show a) => Maybe a -> Expectation

shouldBe (safeHead []) Nothing ::                       Expectation -- but what's `a`?
```

As you can see, `a` is completely ambiguous. It can a be any type that has `Show` and `Eq` instances. This is also part of your error message:

```
No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘shouldBe’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

So pick one:

```
it "returns Nothing for an empty list" $
    safeHead [] `shouldBe` (Nothing :: Maybe ())
```

While you're at it, use QuickCheck to verify that `safeHead` works like `head`:

```
it "returns Just (head xs) for a non-empty list" $ property $ \(NonEmpty xs) ->
    safeHead xs `shouldBe` (Just (head xs) :: Maybe Integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code tests a Maybe Monad that returns a "Just" value:

```
     import Test.Tasty
     import Test.Tasty.HUnit
     import Data.List         

     main = defaultMain tests

     tests = testGroup "Tests uncons form Data.List"

     [testCase "Show uncons [1,2,3,4] = (1, [2,3,4])" $
     Just (1,[2,3,4]) @=? (uncons [1,2,3,4])]
```